# Can you use Demon's Triangle in Shenmue 2?

Tags: shenmue-2

In Shenmue 2, just before going to Guilin, you learn a move called Demon's Triangle. Is there any opportunity to use this move? I did not encounter any battles after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but not in the «story» mode.

If I recall correctly, there's the «minigame» mode in Shenmue II. In this mode you can play all the minigames you played early in the «story» mode. There you also can fight against all the street fighters you met in Kowloon. So, if you finished the game and got the Demon's triangle move you can use it in these single combats.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no, it cannot be used seeing as there are no free battles after being taught the move. I've always assumed that Yu Suzuki's intention was for the move to carry on into *Shenmue III*, even to the point where it's the move that you use against Lan Di at some point (maybe a little far-fetched, I know), but, alas, I doubt we'll ever find out :(.

xx

Comment: "but, alas, I doubt we'll ever find out": I think we will! → https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ysnet/shenmue-3